# HTML checkbox clicks when I tap elsewhere with iOS

Tags: jquery, forms, ipad

Should I report this as a bug in jquerymobile or safari?

When I view the following HTML page on my desktop machine or Opera mini on the iPad, it does what I expect:

- I click Llama, and the alert tells me it was clicked
- Then I click in the empty space on the page, and nothing happens.

When I view it on a iPad with Safari iOS 5.0.1, it does something wierd:

- I click the Llama, and the alert tells me it was clicked
- Then I click in the empty space on the page, and the alert tells me that Llamas were clicked.

(In the actual application I'm trying to get working, when I click on some *other* button, it tells me that Llamas were clicked).

Is there some work-around so that it clicks the button I'm actually touching with my finger, and not the Llama button?
Or should I tell all my iPad users to ditch Safari until this bug gets fixed?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
        <!--
        When I click the button,
        and then later click some empty area on the page,
        I expect the button to do nothing.
        It actually triggers the button to turn off.
        -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>    

            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1"
class="custom" onClick="alert('Llamas have been clicked !');" />
            <label for="checkbox-1">Llamas</label>
    </html>
```

There's a live version at:
http://jsbin.com/ururer

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed similar behaviors on iPhone, and it seems to be a result of overlapping elements and Safari sometimes doesn't make the right choice on which one gets the click event, possibly the CSS is changing to make the checkbox boundaries enlarge.

Try it without the CSS file and see if you still get the behavior.

It could be due to using onClick in the tag instead of using the jQuery methods to bind the event.

Comment: I tried using the jquery ".bind()" to attach that alert(), instead of the "onClick", and Safari on iPad still has exactly the same problem. It seems to work "correctly" without the CSS file, but it looks icky.